# Why I'm getting the jQuery error "TypeError: $(...).live is not a function " in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete, jquery

Actually I'm trying to implement the autocomplete functionality to one text field but getting the above error, couldn't understand why I'm getting this error. Can you help me in resolving this error? For your reference I'm providing all the necessary code below:

report-student-result.tpl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$control_css_url}ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$control_css_url}autocomplete.css">
<label>Name</label>
            <div class="form-element" id="friends">
              <input type="text" class="" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="{$user_name}" />
            </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  

  var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
  var section_id = $('#section_id').val();

        //attach autocomplete  
        $("#user_name").autocomplete({  

            //define callback to format results  
            source: function(req, add){  

                //pass request to server  
                $.getJSON("report_student_result.php?callback=?op=get_student_names&class_id="+class_id+"&section_id="+section_id, req, function(data) {  

                    //create array for response objects  
                    var suggestions = [];  

                    //process response  
                    $.each(data, function(i, val){                                
                    suggestions.push(val.name);  
                });  

                //pass array to callback  
                add(suggestions);  
            });  
        },  

        //define select handler  
        select: function(e, ui) {  

            //create formatted friend  
            var friend = ui.item.value,  
                span = $("<span>").text(friend),  
                a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({  
                    href: "javascript:",  
                    title: "Remove " + friend  
                }).text("x").appendTo(span);  

                //add friend to friend div  
                span.insertBefore("#user_name");  
            },  

            //define select handler  
            change: function() {  

                //prevent 'to' field being updated and correct position  
                $("#user_name").val("").css("top", 2);  
            }  
        }); 
        //add click handler to friends div  
        $("#friends").click(function(){  

            //focus 'to' field  
            $("#user_name").focus();  
        });  

        //add live handler for clicks on remove links  
        $(".remove", document.getElementById("friends")).live("click", function(){  

            //remove current friend  
            $(this).parent().remove();  

            //correct 'to' field position  
            if($("#friends span").length === 0) {  
                $("#user_name").css("top", 0);  
            }                 
        });                      
    });

</script>
```

Please help me out to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because live() has been removed from jQuery ?

Comment: Which Jquery version you are using ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been removed since version 1.9 and was deprecated since 1.7:

You'll be wanting `on()` now days

```
$('#friends').on("click", ".remove", document.getElementById("friends"), function(){
```

where `#friends` is available on DOM ready. You can't bind `on()` on a dynamical loaded element.

Comment: You probably don't need the third argument. It's optional and not used  in event handler.

Comment: Why do we need the 3rd element?? Its not working without the 3rd element.

Comment: the `3rd` element is what gets excuated. The function for it to run. Without it you wouldn't need a click event :p

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `.on()` instead of `.live()` (deprecated after Jquery 1.7)

`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {});` replaces `.live()`.

Eg:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#elementId ", function(){  alert( "Do here what you want!" );  // jQuery1.7+    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Live() has been removed since 1.9 from jquery.  Please use `on`