# Transform $(…).live in .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i checked my site for errors and i got this in Firebug console:

> TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

for this code

```
 $('#payment-address select[name=\'customer_group_id\']').live('change', function() {
        ......... SOME PHP CODE ....
    });
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110917/1773862) and the solution is to use on().
But the problem is that i don't know javascript/jquery.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you read the docs for [`on()`](http://api.jQuery.com/on/)?

Comment: Yes, but i have zero knowledge in jquery so i didn't managed to get the solution from that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** is:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

So you can do:

```
$('body').on('change', "#payment-address select[name=\'customer_group_id\']" , function() {
    ......... SOME PHP CODE ....
});
```

Comment: The event should be on `$(document)` instead of `$('body')` to 100% match the functionality of `live`.

Comment: It's more efficient to bind the event to the closest static parent which is `body` based on the question since OP is not provide any more informations.

Answer (score 2):

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

---

```
$(document).on('change', "#payment-address select[name=\'customer_group_id\']" , function() {
        //code here
});
```

---

```
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click',"#payment-address select[name=\'customer_group_id\']",function(){
   // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $('#payment-address').on('change',"select[name=\'customer_group_id\']" function() {
    //code here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#payment-address').on('change', 'select[name=\'customer_group_id\']', function() {
        ......... SOME PHP CODE ....
    })
```

This is called event delegation. In this way the event is handled by payment-address (as all events bubble up in the DOM tree), and when payment-address handles the event, it checks the origin agains the supplied selector. So you can have different callbacks with different selectors.

Usually the events are attached in this way to the body, as the body always exists and all events eventually bubble to the body

Answer (score 0):

In order to change to on, you need to be aware of how it works.

An event bubbles up through the DOM tree. If you click on a anchor, the event is also passed to the direct parent, to the parents parent, that parent, etc. This will go al the way up to the document

The other answers have given you the method how to replace them, but I miss this:
You can control how far you let it bubble up:

```
$('#wrapper_of_item').on('click', '.item', function);
```

This will stop the bubbling up beyond `#wrapper_of_item`, thus saving some resources.

---

For the sake of completing the answer, the most basic conversion to `on()` would be this

```
// From
$('.elem1').live('click', someFunction);
$('.elem2').live('click', someFunction);

// To:
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Direct conversion:
    $('.elem1').on('click', someFunction);
    $('.elem2').on('click', someFunction);

    // Or a bit better:
    $('#item1s_closest_wrapper_with_id').on('click', '.elem1', someFunction);
    $('#item2s_closest_wrapper_with_id').on('click', '.elem2', someFunction);

});
```